# Assign values to multiple objects with similar name

Tags: r

Let's say I have five lists for five different climate variables, each of them with similar naming, just differing in the climate variable:

```
# define variables name vector
variables <- c("U", "V", "T", "RH", "GHT") 

# create a list for each variable
for (i in 1:length(variables)) {
  assign(paste0(variables[i], ".list"), list())
}
```

Now I would like to fill the single lists with respective data for each variable.

```
# create some sample data
U.vec <- seq(0,50,10)
V.vec <- seq(10,60,10)
T.vec <- seq(20,70,10)
RH.vec <- seq(30,80,10)
GHT.vec <- seq(0,25,5)
```

This can achieved by a multi-line loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(U.vec)) {
  U.list[[i]] <- U.vec[i]
  V.list[[i]] <- V.vec[i]
  T.list[[i]] <- T.vec[i]
  RH.list[[i]] <- RH.vec[i]
  GHT.list[[i]] <- GHT.vec[i]
}
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this, since at both sides the same variable name is included. Anybody with a hint?

Comment: Why do you want to have these as variables, and not as a named list? E.g. `vecs <- list(U = seq(...), V = seq(...)...)`; then you could just do `lists <- lapply(vecs, as.list)`. Also: (1) instead of `1:length()`, use `seq_along()`. (2) to convert vectors to lists, use `as.list()`, not a for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the hints mb706. The example I provided above might be a bit misleading. In the real case I am not dealing with vectors, but with 4D arrays, which require a special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I never really recommend using assign to make variables. I think they would be better in a list. Anyway, if you wanted to, you could do this. PS, you do not need a loop to make a list. You could just use `as.list`.

```r
U.vec <- seq(0,50,10)
V.vec <- seq(10,60,10)
T.vec <- seq(20,70,10)
RH.vec <- seq(30,80,10)
GHT.vec <- seq(0,25,5)

ls()[grepl("\\.vec", ls())] |>
  Map(f = \(x) get(x, envir = globalenv()) |>
        as.list() |>
        assign(x = paste0(sub("\\.vec", "", x), ".list"), 
               envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer AndS. Unfortunately it gives me error messages, I guess you should get them as well if you run the code you provided above. Well in General I prefer working with lists too, in this case it is just a bit different since I am dealing with 4D arrays and need to split them up on their third dimension. So the real case is not as simple as the example code above suggests. If it was, I would use lists right from the start, of course. But it is more than actually just converting vectors to lists.

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are getting. When I run the code above, I get no error.

Comment: This is what I get: ```Error: unexpected '>' in "ls()[grepl("\\.vec", ls())] |>"```, ```Error: unexpected input in "  Map(f = \"```, ```Error: unexpected '>' in "        as.list() |>"``` and ```Error: unexpected ')' in:
"        assign(x = paste0(sub("\\.vec", "", x), ".list"), 
               envir = .GlobalEnv))"```.

Comment: That means that you have not updated R. the `|>` pipe and the `\()` anonymous function requires a newer version of R than you are using.